# como enviar PDF por email com dompdf

Tags: php, pdf, phpmailer, dompdf

Como faço para enviar um `pdf` gerado por `email` com `dompdf`? Segue abaixo meu código fonte:

```
/* Cria a instância */
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();

/* Carrega seu HTML */

$dompdf->load_html("<p align=\"center\"><img src=\"caminho da imagem\"></p>");


/* Renderiza */
$dompdf->render();

sendMailerPDF("iselect@gmail.com", "teste01", "teste PDF", $dompdf->stream("STS_Brochure_".rand(10,1000).".pdf", array("Attachment" => false)));
```

agora utilizando o `phpmailer` para mandar.

```
function sendMailerPDF($destino, $nome_remetente, $assunto, $mensagem) {
        global $erro;
        $mail = new PHPMailer();
        $mail->IsSMTP(); // ativa smtp
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // ativa autent SMTP
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // ssl ou tls define autenticação como ssl
        $mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
        $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // nome do servidor smtp        
        $mail->Port = 465; // porta do smtp
        $mail->Username = "usuario de acesso"; // usuário de acesso smtp
        $user = $mail->Username;
        $mail->Password = "senha"; // senha
        $mail->IsHTML(true); // define que mensagens serão html
        $mail->SetFrom($user, $nome_remetente); // define remetente
        $mail->Subject = $assunto; //define assunto
        $mail->Body = $mensagem; // define mensagem
        $mail->AddAttachment($mensagem);  // Insere um anexo
        $mail->AddAddress($destino); // define destinatario
        if ($mail->Send()) {
            return true;
        }
        else{
            $erro = $mail->ErrorInfo;
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que não tenha como fazer isso, porque o dompdf ele renderiza a página para gerar o PDF, e no PHPMail você precisa de um arquivo em disco para poder anexar.

Minha sugestão é a seguinte:

1 - Renderize o arquivo e guarde no servidor
2 - Pegue o nome desse arquivo que acabou de renderizar anexe e envie por email
3 - apague o arquivo.